# Multi-line JSON read using Apache PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a JSON file and want to read using Apache Pig.

I tried using the regular `JSONLOADER`, but looks like `JSONLOADER` works only with single line JSON. Then I tried with `Elephant-Bird`. But I am still not able to see the results correctly. Can any one please suggest a solution?

Input :

```
{"employees":[                                          
         {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},              
         {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},                      
         {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}             
]}
```

**Note : I dont want to convert the input in to a single line.**

Script:

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad');       
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN($0#'employees');    
Dump B;
```

Expected result should be :

```
([firstName#John,lastName#Doe])                                      
([firstName#Anna,lastName#Smith])                                 
([firstName#Peter,lastName#Jones])
```

Comment: Hi Siva...can you please answer my question  @Sivasakthi Jayaraman

Comment: JsonLoader or elephantbird loader will always works only with single line . It will not work with multiline. You need to convert your input to single line before passing to pig. One workaround would be write a shell script and call the logic to replace multiline to single line using 'SED' command and then call the pig script in the shell script. This link will help you how to call pig thru shell script. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239338/loading-files-into-pig-and-decompressing-them/26264641#26264641

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by siva, the answer is basically that you do need to change your input to a single line.

> JsonLoader or elephantbird loader will always works only with single
>   line . It will not work with multiline. You need to convert your input
>   to single line before passing to pig. One workaround would be write a
>   shell script and call the logic to replace multiline to single line
>   using 'SED' command and then call the pig script in the shell script.
>   This link will help you how to call pig thru shell script.